# APTANA - Which strange char is that?

Tags: aptana, aptana3

I'm new with aptana and this strange char at end of all lines is really strange to me! Why this?! This is a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess, I'd say they are in the right place to represent the carriage return and newline characters found at the end of each line in a file that uses Windows line endings. Do you have a setting enabled to show hidden characters? It also appears that a >> appears at the beginning of many lines to indicate a tab.

The first of your two mystery characters doesn't look like much of anything, but the second one looks like a stylized pilcrow, an old typesetting symbol used to mark the beginning of a new paragraph and commonly used as a visible representation of a new-line character.

Comment: But how I can hidde this characters again?

Comment: The solution:

It is under Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors. There is a checkbox labeled "Show whitespace characters". If you uncheck this the editor switches back to normal.